# How to give 2 different Hyperlinks in css different colors

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

My aim is that a hyperlink is displayed in a green color. I already have given this hyperlink a class `.ueberschrift_name`.

I tried to change the color with CSS and HTML with no luck. I want to change the color of the existing hyperlink from white to green. I hope someone can give me a hint how to solve this problem for me.

Comment: can you show your html?

Comment: And can you also show what you have tried that did not work

Comment: <a href="http://puravidas.ch/index.php/ueber-mich.html" style="color: #CC0000">Melanie Bircher</a>

Comment: If you add the colour directly on the element using the style attribute, this will override the CSS. Best of setting its initial value in CSS first off

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What do you think is wrong on this code?

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML and CSS code - *only* the relevant code!

Comment: I get what you mean, but can you give me maybe a specific example how do you think it should work?

Comment: @abdi, you're missing a semicolon on the end there, it should be style="color: #CC0000;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the "ueberschrift_name" class to your HTML element. Then add the     following:

**CSS:**

```
.ueberschrift_name{
    color: red;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="default.asp" class="ueberschrift_name" target="_blank">This is a link</a>
```

**JSfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/zLofsecL/

---

**OR - you can use inline styles:**

```
<a href="default.asp" style="color: red;" target="_blank">This is a link</a>
```

Comment: <a href="http://puravidas.ch/index.php/ueber-mich.html" class="ueberschrift_name" target="_blank">Melanie Bircher</a>

Comment: ok, so know I added the CSS and HTML code, did you see an error in my code, because it didn't work now...

Comment: Yes, thank you! I copied the html code and then I gave a:link instead of the white color my prefered color and after that my problem was solved :)

Answer (score 0):

It probably doesn't work because of CSS selector priority.

Easy solution (not really recommended):

```
.ueberschrift_name {color: green !important;}
```

Better solution: figure out which rule is setting the colour of the links to white, then copy that line of code and append your class, and set it to green. E.g.:

```
.my-parent-class a {color: white;}
.my-parent-class a.ueberschrift_name {color: green;}
```

Comment: Thanks for your 2 solutions, I tried the first one and it didn't work. I used the !important a few times but thats the first time it didnt work properly to overwrite the white color to green...

Comment: @Abdi In that case post your html and css as many have already asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a class for each of your anchor text hyperlinks.

```
<div>
<a href="#" class="green-name"><h2>Name 1</h2></a>
<a href="#" class="white-name"><h2>Name 2</h2></a>
</div>
```

Then simply define the color in your CSS, if you don't see any changes try using the !important rule to override:

```
.green-name {color: green !important;}

.white-name {color:white !important;}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: <a href="http://puravidas.ch/index.php/ueber-mich.html" class="ueberschrift_name" target="Melanie Bircher</a>

Comment: the problem is that the a: visited overvwrite the white color I gave him my other Hyperlink..

Comment: a:visited {
    font-size: 55px;
    color: #ffffff;
}